# I would like to have multiple variables posted at once

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have an option panel which inserts an variable and posts this into the database. But i would like to select multiple variables to post at once.

the selection html

```
<select name="werknemer[]" data-placeholder="Werknemers..." style="width:160px;" class="chzn-select" id="werknemer"  tabindex="4">
                    <option value=""></option> 
                <?if($werknemers !=null):foreach($werknemers as $row):?>
                    <option value='<?=$row->idWerknemer;?>'><?=$row->Voornaam;?>&nbsp;(<?=$row->Achternaam;?>)</option> 
                <?endforeach;endif;?>
            </select>
```

process.php:

```
        $q = "INSERT INTO evenement (id,idWerknemer,idProject,idKlant,idTaak,title,description,start,end,color) VALUES 
            ('','".$user_werknemer."','".$user_project."','".$user_klant."','".$user_taak."','".$user_name."','".$user_desc."','".$user_start."','".$user_end."','".$user_color."')";
        $qo = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger (idWerknemer,idProject,idEvent,idKlant,idTaak) VALUES ('".$user_werknemer."','".$user_project."','','".$user_klant."','".$user_taak."')";

    mysql_query($q);
    mysql_query($qo);
    }


if(isset($_POST['user_werknemer'],$_POST['user_project'],$_POST['user_klant'],$_POST['user_taak'],$_POST['user_name'],$_POST['user_desc'],$_POST['user_start'],$_POST['user_starttime'],$_POST['user_endtime'],$_POST['user_end'],$_POST['user_color'],$_POST['action'])){
        $user_werknemer=$_POST['user_werknemer'];
        $user_color=$_POST['user_color'];
        $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
        $user_desc=$_POST['user_desc'];
        $user_project=$_POST['user_project'];
        $user_klant=$_POST['user_klant'];
        $user_taak=$_POST['user_taak'];
        $user_start=$_POST['user_start']." ".$_POST['user_starttime'];
        $user_end=$_POST['user_end']." ".$_POST['user_endtime'];
        $action=$_POST['action'];
        if ($action=='joined'){
            user_joined( $user_werknemer, $user_project, $user_klant, $user_taak, $user_name, $user_desc, $user_start, $user_end, $user_color);
            }
    }
/*if ( (isset($_POST["id"]) && strlen($_POST["id"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["id"]) <= 60) &&
    (isset($_POST["name"]) && strlen($_POST["name"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["name"]) <= 50) &&
    (isset($_POST["age"]) && strlen($_POST["age"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["age"]) <= 40) ) 
{   //check $_POST["name"] and $_POST["address"] and $_POST["city"] are not empty

    $id   = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age   = $_POST["age"];

    $q = "INSERT INTO tbltest ( id, name, age) VALUES 
            ('".$id."','".$name."','".$age."')";
    mysql_query($q); 

}*/

?>
```

the dialog to insert the values:

```
$(function () {
// Dialog Open   
$("#d1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape:true, 
    resizable:false, 
    show:'fade',
    buttons: { 
      "Add": function() { 

        var id = $("#id").val(),
        werknemer = $('#werknemer').val(),
        project = $('#project').val(),
        klant = $('#klant').val(),
        taak = $('#taak').val(),
        name = $('#name').val(),
        desc = $('#desc').val(),
        start = $('#start').val(),
        starttime = $('#starttime').val(),
        end = $('#end').val(),
        endtime = $('#endtime').val();
        colorstatus = $('#colorstatus').val();

        if(id=='' || werknemer=='' || name=='' || desc=='' || start=='' || end=='')
            {
                //alert("Please do not empty....!",title="Hello");
                $("#d2").dialog("open");
                $("#d2").dialog({
                    buttons:{
                        "OK":function(){
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                $("#id:first").focus(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                exit;
            }//End if statement

        $.post('../testcalendar/db/process.php',{
            user_id: id, user_werknemer: werknemer, user_project: project, user_klant: klant,user_taak: taak, user_name: name, user_desc: desc, user_start: start, user_starttime: starttime, user_end: end, user_endtime: endtime, user_color: colorstatus, action:'joined'
        }); var nTime = 1 * 50;

        window.setTimeout("location.reload()", nTime);//End Post
        $("#id").val('');
        $("#werknemer").val('');
        $("#project").val('');
        $("#klant").val('');
        $("#taak").val('');
        $("#name").val('');
        $("#desc").val('');
        $("#start").val('');    
        $("#starttime").val('');
        $("#end").val('');  
        $("#endtime").val('');          
        $("#colorstatus").val('');          
        $(this).dialog("close");        
        },
      "Cancel": function() { 
        $("#id").val('');
        $("#werknemer").val('');
        $("#project").val('');
        $("#klant").val('');
        $("#taak").val('');
        $("#name").val('');
        $("#desc").val('');
        $("#start").val('');
        $("#starttime").val('');
        $("#end").val('');
        $("#endtime").val('');  
        $("#colorstatus").val('');  
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
    }
});


$("#d2").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape:true, 
    resizable:false, 
    show:'fade',
    buttons: { 
      "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } 
    }
});

$("#b1").click(function(){
    $("#d1").dialog("open");
});
$("#start").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$("#end").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$('input[type="time"] ').timepicker();
});

function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

i thought i need to do something with the multiple style tag in the html and then in the php a foreach loop like this

```
 <?php
//include db configuration file
include 'connection.php';
function user_joined($user_werknemer,$user_project,$user_klant,$user_taak,$user_name,$user_desc, $user_start, $user_startdate, $user_starttime, $user_end, $user_enddate, $user_endtime, $user_color){

        $q = "INSERT INTO evenement (id,title,description,start,startdate,starttime,end,enddate,endtime,color) VALUES 
            ('','".$user_name."','".$user_desc."','".$user_start."','".$user_startdate."','".$user_starttime."','".$user_end."','".$user_enddate."','".$user_endtime."','".$user_color."') ";


            foreach($user_werknemer as $test){
        $qo = "INSERT INTO evenementontvanger (idWerknemer,idProject,idEvent,idKlant,idTaak) VALUES ('".$test."','".$user_project."',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$user_klant."','".$user_taak."')";
mysql_query($qo);}

    mysql_query($q);

    }


if(isset($_POST['user_werknemer'],$_POST['user_project'],$_POST['user_klant'],$_POST['user_taak'],$_POST['user_name'],$_POST['user_desc'],$_POST['user_startdate'],$_POST['user_start'],$_POST['user_starttime'],$_POST['user_enddate'],$_POST['user_endtime'],$_POST['user_end'],$_POST['user_color'],$_POST['action'])){
        $user_werknemer=$_POST['user_werknemer'];
        $user_color=$_POST['user_color'];
        $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
        $user_desc=$_POST['user_desc'];
        $user_project=$_POST['user_project'];
        $user_klant=$_POST['user_klant'];
        $user_taak=$_POST['user_taak'];
        $user_start=$_POST['user_startdate']." ".$_POST['user_starttime'];
        $user_startdate=$_POST['user_startdate'];
        $user_starttime=$_POST['user_starttime'];
        $user_end=$_POST['user_enddate']." ".$_POST['user_endtime'];
        $user_enddate=$_POST['user_enddate'];
        $user_endtime=$_POST['user_endtime'];
        $action=$_POST['action'];
        if ($action=='joined'){
            user_joined( $user_werknemer, $user_project, $user_klant, $user_taak, $user_name, $user_desc, $user_start, $user_startdate, $user_starttime, $user_end, $user_enddate, $user_endtime, $user_color);
            }
    }
/*if ( (isset($_POST["id"]) && strlen($_POST["id"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["id"]) <= 60) &&
    (isset($_POST["name"]) && strlen($_POST["name"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["name"]) <= 50) &&
    (isset($_POST["age"]) && strlen($_POST["age"]) >= 3 && strlen($_POST["age"]) <= 40) ) 
{   //check $_POST["name"] and $_POST["address"] and $_POST["city"] are not empty

    $id   = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age   = $_POST["age"];

    $q = "INSERT INTO tbltest ( id, name, age) VALUES 
            ('".$id."','".$name."','".$age."')";
    mysql_query($q); 

}*/

?>
```

but i dont know how to run the same mysql query for each "werknemer" selected

For the dutch people as followed:
ik heb een optie paneel wat een variable post. Maar ik wil meerdere variabelen tegelijk meesturen. hiervoor dacht ik aan een multiple option paneel. en een foreach loop. Dit werkt wel deels, want wanneer ik meerdere variabelen ("in dit geval werknemers") selecteer post hij ook meerdere rijen met data. Alleen het id van de werknemer post hij niet meer. Graag zou ik willen dat de id van de werknemer ook gepost wordt.

Comment: Please also post your question in Dutch, i might be able to help but your english is the same like mine: not very goed :)

Comment: Well either you put everything belonging to your query (preparation, execution) _into_ the loop, or you create a multiple insert-query in your loop and execute it once after the loop.

Comment: i've edited it. The foreach works here. but only the evenement.id isnt set in evenementontvanger.idEvent when multiple user_werknemers are selected.